# PHP Stripe API error on add payment source from token

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am getting the below error[image: Stripe api error]:-

I Think I am not getting the $payment_source_id, rather am unable to generate the $payment_source_id,

from this

```
$payment_source_id = $this->add_payment_source_from_token( $customer_id, $token_id, 
$invoice );
```

Its corresponding function is :-

```
private function add_payment_source_from_token( $customer_id, $token_id, SI_Invoice 
$invoice ) {
$customer = self::get_customer_object( $customer_id );
if ( ! $customer ) {
do_action( 'si_error', __CLASS__ . '::' . __FUNCTION__ . ' response: ', $customer );
return;
}
self::setup_stripe();
try {
$card = $customer->sources->create( array( 'source' => $token_id ) );
} catch (Exception $e) {
self::set_error_messages( $e->getMessage() );
return false;
}
$source_id = $card->id;
if ( ! isset( $_POST['sa_credit_store_payment_profile'] ) && ! isset( $checkout- 
>cache['sa_credit_store_payment_profile'] ) ) 
{Sprout_Billings_Profiles::hide_payment_profile( $source_id, $invoice->get_id() );}
return $source_id;
}
```

Any one could you please point out where am going wrong and what it should be, I think that will resolve the issue here, it will be a great help. Early response will be highly appreciated, Thanks in advance. By the way **My stripe library is stripe-php-6.31.0**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error `Call to a member function create() on null`, I am assuming the error originates on this line:

```
$card = $customer->sources->create( array( 'source' => $token_id ) );
```

This is likely because the Customer [`sources` are expandable](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object?lang=php#customer_object-sources), meaning they are not returned by default. You must explicitly [request expanded properties](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) during retrieval. For Customer sources in `stripe-php` prior to the [changes in 7.33.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/wiki/Migration-to-StripeClient-and-services-in-7.33.0) this would be:

```
\Stripe\Customer::retrieve([
  'id' => 'cus_123',
  'expand' => ['sources']
]);
```

For 7.33.0+ it would be:

```
$stripe->customers->retrieve(
  'cus_123',
  ['expand' => ['sources']]
);
```

I'm not sure how you can pass the `expand` parameter with `get_customer_object` but you'll need to investigate that separately.

Comment: Am trying to generate sources from here, but unfortunately, I cant:-                                            
public static function get_payment_profiles( $profile_id = 0 ) {
$sources = $customer->sources->all();
if ( empty( $sources ) ) {return array();}
$cards = array();
foreach ( $sources->data as $key => $card ) {
$desc = ( isset( $card->brand ) ) ? $card->brand : $card->bank_name ;
$cards[ $card->id ] = $desc . ': ' . $card->last4;
}return $cards;}

Comment: Can you edit your question to add this with some details about any errors or unexpected results? The code here is hard to read and it doesn't appear to include any error reference.

Comment: Thanks, its working now. By expand => ['sources'] this has been working like champ :)